# Magento - List Products Categories

Tags: magento

In Magento on each products detail page I would like to list which categories which belongs to.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
```

and also

```
 $categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
  ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
  ->addAttributeToSelect('url')
  ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
  ->addIsActiveFilter();
```

Cheers,
JD

Comment: @silvo `category_ids` still appears in my `eav_attribute` table with `attribute_id` = 91. Where did you hear about deprecation? I haven't seen an official announcement about any deprecations, it would be interesting to read...

Comment: I read about problems with this attribute in the comments to this blog: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-filter-product-collection-using-2-or-more-category-filters/. However, it seems that it's ok.

Comment: Not a really useful answer. I have no idea where I'm supposed to put that code in order to get it to work! MAgento sucks.

Comment: @imjp - not really a helpful comment.  StackOverflow is intended to provide responses to specific questions, not be a full tutorial.  Make the effort to read some of the excellent tutorials on the Magento site and elsewhere and you'll find that this answer is perfectly helpful.  And lose the attitude if you want people to help. Oh, and since you asked so nicely, try app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to display all categories related to the selected product in the product detail page.

```
<?php $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>
           <?php foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id): ?>
           <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id) ?> 
            <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: This works great! Only one thing though, say we wanted to NOT list a particular category ID (or several category IDs) in the output, how would that be achieved with this code, please?

Answer (score 0):

The  code will get product category name based on store id. This will also use full for multi store and multiwebsite concepts

```
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
   $cats = $product->getCategoryIds(); 
   foreach ($cats as $category_id) {
   $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()-  >getStore()->getId())->load($category_id);
    echo $_cat->getName();             
     }
```